# Can't interpolate error passing $scope variable in to a angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, interpolation, angularjs-filter

I have a angular filter that converts a user id to a user image url by checking if the id exist in a array and returns the corresponding image url, the array is passed with the filter.
The filter is working and the ng-repeat list shows me the correct image url's but there are 2 errors in my console.
The first errors is on line 4 and the second error is in ionic.bundle.js:13380:32

Errors:

> Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'members.length')
>  Error:
>   [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{ participant.athlete_id |
>   idToImage : clubMembers }} TypeError: undefined is not an object
>   (evaluating 'members.length')

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="participant in participants | filter:{ event_id: event.id }: true track by $index">
    <img ng-src="{{ participant.athlete_id | idToImage : clubMembers }}">
</div>
```

Angular filter:

```
1 app.filter('idToImage', function () {
2   return function (id, members) {
3       var curMember = id;
4        var len = members.length - 1;
5        while(len >= 0){
6           if(curMember >= members[len].id){
7               return members[len].profile;
8           }
9           len--;
10        }
11     };
12 });
```

clubMemers in {{ participant.athlete_id | idToImage : clubMembers }} is a array like the example below, and is retrieved from a external source:

```
$scope. clubMembers = [
   {"id":1234,"profile":"https://domain.net/pictures/1.jpg"},
   {"id":12345,"profile":"https://domain.net/pictures/3.jpg"},
   {"id":12346,"profile":"https://domain.net/pictures/4.jpg"}
]
```

Comment: can you check values for arguments when call filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your filter is not handling that condition when `members` is empty, because when you don't gonna handle it `members.length` will be messed up and code execution will stop at that point.

**Filter**

```
app.filter('idToImage', function () {
   return function (id, members) {
       if(!members) return; //return nothing in this case
       var curMember = id;
        var len = members.length - 1; //checking above if before processing members
        while(len >= 0){
           if(curMember >= members[len].id){
               return members[len].profile;
           }
           len--;
        }
    }
});
```